# Returning an ActiveRecord Object from two different Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to return an ActiveRecord object consisting of two different objects from two different tables.  They have the following relations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy

  # Ideally user.timeline returns all of a user's posts and pictures as an active record relation.

  def timeline
      Post.where("(user_id = :user_id)", user_id: id)
      Picture.where("(user_id = :user_id)", user_id: id)    
  end
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to be able to call user.timeline and have all of a user's posts and pictures returned together as one active record relation.

I have tried:
    Post.where("(user_id = :user_id)", user_id: id) + Picture.where("(user_id = :user_id)", user_id: id).  This returns all the objects I want, but as an array, not an active record relation.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Do `posts` and `pictures` have the same structure? Presumably they don't but if they did you could do an SQL UNION to mash them together. Have you considered merging `Post` and `Picture` so that you'd have "items" that could contain a post or a picture? Then you'd just do `some_user.items` and sort out the difference when you display the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should use another table to handle the timeline.

```
Timeline
user_id:integer
post_id:integer
picture_id:integer
```

Each time user send a pic or post, it should also create a record in timeline which indicates the post_id or picture_id or whatever you want.

I prefer not using foreign key due to the performance issue as this is a timeline model.

Then you might be able to do query like this.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def timeline
    Timeline.where(user_id: id)
  end
end
```

You can use timeline model to serialize the model for each record.

Comment: Thank you very much, I went with this answer.  Instead of trying to write a query that returned both types of objects, this was an easier and much more practical answer.  

I placed an after_save callback after the creation of Post and Picture objects to record it on the Timeline table, as was suggested.